# Verbs for subscribing to a proposition

Tags: single-word-requests

When A believes that the proposition p is true, we may say

> A *subscribes to* the proposition that ...

Which verbs may replace the italicized expression without altering the
meaning of the sentence?

Answers should be either suitable to academic prose or archaic.

Answer (score 2):

One may **espouse** or **embrace** a proposition, particularly if it is a deeply-held belief.

If the person actively **supports** the proposition, in addition to simply believing it is true, you could also say that they **champion**, **endorse**, or **advocate** it.

Answer (score 1):

"Believes"!

There is also "accepts", and possibly in some contexts "adopts".

Answer (score 1):

A **adheres** to the proposition that ...

The usage especially fits the general idea supported by *[subscribing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subscribe)* to an idea: one is supporting or attesting to that idea. In the Merriam-Webster dictionary, "[Adhere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adhere)" refers to supporting or assenting to an idea (meaning 2):

> 1 : to hold fast or stick by or as if by gluing, suction, grasping, or fusing
>
> The stamp failed to adhere to the envelope.
>
> 2 : **to give support or maintain loyalty**
>
> adhere to traditional values
>
> 3 : to bind oneself to observance
>
> adhere to the rules

Answer (score 0):

**concurs with**, a little more formal than **agrees with.**

In British English, “agree” is sometimes used with a direct object, e.g., “agree the treaty.”